# previous_post_link inside of a function?

Tags: functions, filters, actions

I'm missing something on how to call previous_post_link() inside of a function. I also tried assigning the output to a string variable and using that.

```
function prevnext( $content ) {
    $content .= '<div>' . previous_post_link() . '-' . next_post_link() . '</div>';
    return $content;
}
add_action( 'the_content', 'prevnext', 4 );
```

I get the hyphen - but not the links. Substituting another string variable also prints to the screen. I can use previous_post_link() in the page template and it works fine. What am I not doing right?

Comment: try this inside function and replace to get_previous_post_link() or get_next_post_link()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` should work inside the `the_content` filter.

There is nothing wrong with your code except you must return the value inside the filter instead of print. Otherwise I believe post link should be there at the beginning of content.

`previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` print the output so consider using `get_previous_post_link()` and `get_next_post_link()`.

```
function prevnext( $content ) {
    $content .= '<div>' . get_previous_post_link() . '-' . get_next_post_link() . '</div>';
    return $content;
}
add_action( 'the_content', 'prevnext', 4 );
```

Comment: Duh! Sometimes I amaze myself. I knew that. Thanks for pointing it out. That was all I needed to do - use get_